# Package newtxmath with ebgaramond option enabled throws an error

Tags: fonts, errors, newtxmath

Compiling documents with the `[ebgaramond]` option of the `newtxmath` package enabled throws me the following error:

```
No file OMLntxebgmi.fd.

! LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.
```

What might be causing this?

---

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

I get an error as soon as I change `\usepackage{newtxmath}` to `\usepackage[ebgaramond]{newtxmath}`.

Also, I'm using `newtxmath` version `1.602` dated `2019/10/09`.

Also also, the full log file of the failing version can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/BsRxSm3m)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post the MWE and the information about the packages as part of the question, not in comments!!!

Comment: Hi, campa! I've edited the question. Sorry for not including them before. (P.S. I've also deleted my comments hoping to unclutter the question/comments a bit)

Comment: Show your log-file (of the failing version).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You can find the log file here: https://pastebin.com/BsRxSm3m.

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me. You have a number of packages that are older than mine and most importantly your newtx package is older and seem to be missing an fd-file. Check for updates with the texlive manager.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yup, it was an outdated package(s?) problem. After an update, the minimal non-working example is now an MWE. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by an update.